# Changing my site from HTTP to HTTPS - will google search results sort themselves out?

Tags: google, google-search-console, https, search-results

I've made all of my http pages 301 redirect to their https equivalents.

I've also made sure that all of the URLs in my sitemap files are https.

Lastly I created a new profile in GWTs under the https version of the site, and submitted the sitemaps in there (and removed them from the http version of the site).  I suspect this was unnecessary, but I don't think it'll have done any harm.

Is there anything else I need to do, or is it just a matter of time for google to re-crawl and update their index?

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow did the same thing. See Google's *official* answer in the question I marked this as a duplicate of.

Comment: Stack Overflow *hasn't* done the same thing yet, @JohnConde, but is planning to.

Comment: Well I can confirm that google did eventually move all of their results for my site over to https - it took quite a while though, I got bored of checking and haven't looked again until today.  Some were very quickly changed, but others persisted for weeks, even with a change to site content on every page and a sitemap reflecting this change.